# is it possible to get metamask account name using web3 or any other way?

Tags: api, account, web3js, metamask

I've tried to search in Metamask doc, but I did not find anything about the account info, so is there any API or can I use Web3 to get the account name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MetaMask does not share the account name over its API. Only the currently selected address and network, if the user explicitly confirms this action.